# How to find similarity between different variables according to consequent string values in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, similarity

I have a DF structured like this:

```
 X  Y  Z 
 D  E  1
 D  F  2
 D  G  3
 L  E  1
 L  F  2
 L  G  3
 M  N  4
 M  O  5
 S  N  4
 S  O  5
```

i want to obtain two different clusters ("L - D", "M - S"), according to the second column values which they have in common. So, the output would be structured like this:

```
 Clust.1   Clust.2
    L         M
    D         S
```

How could i do?

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Can you show the exact expected output?

Comment: @Sagar it is simply a new data frame made by a varying number of columns, according to the number of clusters which emerge after the analysis

Comment: It will be helpful for others to know what you expect as output. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea via `tidyverse`,

```
df %>% 
 group_by(X) %>% 
 summarise(Z = toString(Z)) %>% 
 group_by(Z) %>% 
 mutate(new = seq(n())) %>% 
 spread(Z, X)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>     new `1, 2, 3` `4, 5`
> * <int>    <fctr> <fctr>
> 1     1         D      M
> 2     2         L      S
> ```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you very much!